# Why does Python evaluate "foo" in "bar" != "baz" as False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While reviewing some Python code, I encountered some bad logic. But, I don't understand how it is getting evaluated. The code amounts to this:

```py
>>> "foo" in "bar" != "baz"
False
```

How is this False? The "in" and "!=" have the same order of precedence. If the "in" is evaluated first:

```py
>>> ("foo" in "bar") != "baz"
True
```

because False is not equal to "baz". But if "!=" has precedence, then this should raise an exception:

```py
>>> "foo" in ("bar" != "baz")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    "foo" in ("bar" != "baz")
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

So, for the first example, without parentheses, what is going on?

Comment: TL;DR `"foo" in "bar" != "baz"` is evaluated as `"foo" in "bar" and "bar" != "baz"`

Comment: Also, use parenthesis.  There's no awards for having less characters in the source file.

Comment: Thanks. So, to summarize, this is treated as a chained operation. Not intuitive, but something to keep in mind.